# Utilizar método altera java

Tags: java, jdbc

Como eu faço alteração no banco de dados utilizando o método altera em uma classe TestaAltera. Eu utilizo os gets e sets do modelo para alterar os dados?
Eu preciso utilizar o método PesquisaId(int id) para retornar um objeto?

```
//pesquisa pelo id e retorna um contato
public Contato pesquisarId(int id) {

    try {
        String sql = "select * from contatos where id = " + id;

        Contato contato = new Contato();

        PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            contato.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            contato.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            contato.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            contato.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));

            Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
            data.setTime(rs.getDate("dataNascimento"));
            contato.setDataNascimento(data);

        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return contato;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

//altera
public void altera(Contato contato) {

    String sql = "update contatos set nome=?, email=? where id = id";

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

         stmt.setString(1, contato.getNome());
         stmt.setString(2, contato.getEmail());
         stmt.setString(3, contato.getEndereco());
         stmt.setDate(4, new Date(contato.getDataNascimento().getTimeInMillis()));
         stmt.setLong(5, contato.getId());

         stmt.execute();
         stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Resumindo como ficaria a classe altera?

```
    package br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste;

import br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao;
import br.com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato;

public class TesteAltera {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();

        Contato contato = dao.pesquisarId(1);


        dao.altera(contato);

    }

}
```

Comment: Para que ele persista novos dados no comando update, você simplesmente tem de atribuir novos valores à 'contato', não? `contato.setNome("Fulano");` etc...

Comment: AEE deu certooo

Comment: Gabriel, vou responder sua pergunta para que a pergunta possa ser fechada. Obs.: Não defina um novo id para o registro que você buscou da tabela. Se possível, favor avaliar minha resposta.

Comment: @GabrielFaria não precisa você colocar como título que foi RESOLVIDO seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

A classe deverá se parecer com algo como isto:

```
public class TesteAltera {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();

    Contato contato = dao.pesquisarId(1);

    contato.setNome("Ciclano");
    contato.setEmail("ciclano@hotmail.com");
    contato.setEndereco("Av. das Nações, 147");
    Calendar novaData = Calendar.getInstance();

    contato.setDataNascimento(novaData);

    dao.altera(contato);

}

}
```

Para que você altere um registro do banco de dados dentro de um programa Java, primeiro você precisa recuperá-lo e colocar seus valores dentro de um objeto. Neste caso, `contato`.

Após isto, você altera seus valores para os desejados e finalmente, manda o objeto ser persistido pelo método `altera()` para que os dados do banco sejam alterados de acordo com os dados que se encontram no objeto.

Comment: Opa, arrumei aqui. Realmente essa solução é melhor. Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

A classe ficou assim:

```
    package br.com.caelum.jdbc.teste;

import java.util.Calendar;

import br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao;
import br.com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.Contato;

public class TesteAltera {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();

        Contato contato = new Contato();

        long id = 1;

        contato.setId(id);
        contato.setNome("Nathalia");
        contato.setEmail("nath@Gmail.com");
        contato.setEndereco("Av. Paula Ferreira");
        Calendar novaData = Calendar.getInstance();

        contato.setDataNascimento(novaData);

        dao.altera(contato);

    }

}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o funcionamento? É um assunto que me interessa, grato. Nota: coloque a explicação dentro da resposta, edite ela.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Para que você altere um registro do banco de dados dentro de um programa Java, primeiro você precisa recuperá-lo e colocar seus valores dentro de um objeto. Neste caso, `contato`. Após isto, você altera seus valores para os desejados e finalmente, manda o objeto ser persistido pelo método `altera()` para que os dados do banco sejam alterados de acordo com os dados que se encontram no objeto.

Comment: Nota: coloque a explicação dentro da resposta, edite ela.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Se esse assunto te interessa, recomendo que dê uma olhada nas apostilas da Caelum, estou estudando por lá. Esses exercícios são da apostila de Java para Desenvolvimento Web.

Comment: @GabrielFaria acho que não entendeu o foco do site, aqui procuramos fornecer respostas detalhadas com o intuito de ajudar a quem tem a duvida atual como futuros visitantes, isto ainda pode lhe garantir alguns upvotes, recomendo que explique o código, por mais que seja uma breve explicação ;)